# How do I create an ElasticSearch query without knowing what the field is?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api

I have someone putting JSON objects into Elasticsearch for which I do not know any fields. I would like to search *all* the fields for a given value using a matchQuery.

I understand that the _all is deprecated, and the copy_to doesn't work because I don't know what fields are available beforehand. Is there a way to accomplish this without knowing what fields to search for beforehand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can achieve this using a custom `_all` field (which I called `my_all`) and a dynamic template for your index. Basically, this idea is to have a generic mapping for all fields with a `copy_to` setting to the `my_all` field. I've also added `store: true` for the `my_all` field but only for the purpose of showing you that it works, in practice you won't need it.

So let's go and create the index:

```
PUT my_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "dynamic_templates": [
        {
          "all_fields": {
            "match": "*",
            "mapping": {
              "copy_to": "my_all"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "properties": {
        "my_all": {
          "type": "text",
          "store": true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then index a document:

```
PUT my_index/_doc/1
{
  "test": "the cat drinks milk",
  "age": 10,
  "alive": true,
  "date": "2018-03-21T10:00:00.123Z",
  "val": ["data", "data2", "data3"]
}
```

Finally, we can search using the `my_all` field and also show its content (because we store its content) in addition to the `_source` of the document:

```
GET my_index/_search?q=my_all:cat&_source=true&stored_fields=my_all
```

And the result is shown below:

```
  {
    "_index": "my_index",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "1",
    "_score": 0.2876821,
    "_source": {
      "test": "the cat drinks milk",
      "age": 10,
      "alive": true,
      "date": "2018-03-21T10:00:00.123Z",
      "val": [
        "data",
        "data2",
        "data3"
      ]
    },
    "fields": {
      "my_all": [
        "the cat drinks milk",
        "10",
        "true",
        "2018-03-21T10:00:00.123Z",
        "data",
        "data2",
        "data3"
      ]
    }
  }
```

So given you can create the index and mapping of your index, you'll be able to search whatever people are sending to it.